# How can I embed one DropWizard (with freemarker) View in another one?

Tags: java, templates, freemarker, dropwizard

I am using DropWizard and Freemarker to build up a view which displays different types of forms based on results from a webservice.

I have created the forms as views - each with their own ftl.

So, in my resource, I discover which form I need, then load the main.ftl, passing the form view as a parameter (see below).

This doesn't work.  Can anyone see where we're going wrong?  Or is there a completely different way to chain views together using DropWizard and freemarker?

```
@GET
public Form getForm() {
        FormView view = new FormView(service.getForm());
        return new MainView(view);
}

public class FormView extends View {
    private final Form form;

    public FormView(Form form) {
        super("formView.ftl");
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Form getForm() {
        return form;
    }
}

public class MainView extends View {
    private final FormView formView;

    public MainView(FormView formView) {
        super("main.ftl");
        this.formView = formView;
    }

    public FormView getFormView() {
        return formView;
    }
}

public class TextForm extends View implements Form {
    private int maxLength;
    private String text;

    public TextForm(int maxLength, String text) {
        super("textForm.ftl");
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

main.ftl
<#-- @ftlvariable formView="" type="MainView" -->
<html>
<body>
    <#include formView.templateName />  // This evaluates to formView.ftl, but it seems to create a new instance, and doesn't have the reference to textForm.ftl. How do we reference a dropwizard view here?
</body>
</html>

formView.ftl
<#-- @ftlvariable form type="FormView" -->
${form?html}   // also tried #include form.templateName

textForm.ftl
<#-- @ftlvariable text type="TextForm" -->
<div>${text?html}</div>
```

Comment: In `main.ftl`, `formView` needs to evaluate to either `formView.ftl` or `textView.ftl`.  It's not clear to me from your code snippet that this is the case, but I'm unfamiliar with DropWizard.

Comment: Thanks. Using <#include formView.templateName />  evaluates to formView.ftl, but it seems to create a new instance, and doesn't have the reference to textForm.ftl

Comment: My understanding was that you wanted to choose either `formView.ftl` or `textForm.ftl` depending on the value of `formView.templateName`, but you want both?  Or is it that `textView.ftl` is not being chosen when you expect it to be?  I'm confused.

Comment: I want formView.ftl to be a container, including either textForm.ftl or (e.g.) numberForm.ftl, complexForm.ftl or lazyForm.ftl depending on comes back from the webservice.  So there are three levels of template embedding: mainView.ftl contains a FormView, which contains one of TextForm/NumberForm/ComplexForm/LazyForm

Answer (score 3):

Based on the discussion, I *think* you need something like this:

```
<#-- main.ftl -->
<html>
<body>
    <#include formView.templateName>
</body>
</html>
```

`formView.templateName` must evaluate to `textForm.ftl`, `numberForm.ftl`, `complexForm.ftl` or whatever form view you might have.  There's no need for an intermediate file that chooses between these.  I think you are running into problems because `FormView.getTemplateName()` is returning a hard-coded `formView.ftl`.  I *think* that what you need is for this method to return the name of the actual template file containing the form type you want to display.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out how to do this.

You make a `TemplateView` class (see below) that extends `View`.
Then all your View classes need to extend `TemplateView` instead.

The constructor takes an extra parameter, the "body" template file, that is the body to go inside the template.

Then, inside your template file, do something like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>My template file</h1>
          <#include body>
      <footer>footer etc</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `TemplateView` class.

```
public abstract class TemplateView extends View
{
    private final String body;

    protected TemplateView(String layout, String body)
    {
        super(layout);
        this.body = resolveName(body);
    }

    public String getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }

    private String resolveName(String templateName)
    {
        if (templateName.startsWith("/"))
        {
            return templateName;
        }
        final String packagePath = getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/');
        return String.format("/%s/%s", packagePath, templateName);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.