# Dropwizard View includes several Freemarker templates

Tags: freemarker, dropwizard

I use the Views with Freemarker to Display HTML info pages. Now I want to add a "footer" for all templates, but I dont want to copy same code to every *.ftl file.

Is it possible to create one footer.ftl and add it to all other *.ftl files? Searching web, i found freemarker macros, but I dont know how to use it in DW. How can I use freemarker macros with DW?

This doesn't help -> [How can I embed one DropWizard (with freemarker) View in another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664760/how-can-i-embed-one-dropwizard-with-freemarker-view-in-another-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added just this line to the original ftl:

```
<p><#include "footer.ftl"> </p>
```

This file is in the same folder (I havent tried other locations) and contains the footer text like:

```
Copyright 2001-2002<br>
All rights reserved.
```